# Need to construct query which will find parents of a record in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to construct a query on a single table. The table structure and some dummy data in it as follows

```
id  | username  | seniorid
1   | Superuser |   -1
2   | user1 |    1
3   | user2 |    1
4   | user3 |    3
5   | user4 |    4
6   | user5 |    1
7   | user6 |    6
8   | user7 |    6
9   | user8 |    8
10  | user9 |    9
11  | user10    |    8
12  | user11    |    8
13  | user12    |    8
14  | user13    |    6
15  | user14    |    3
16  | user15    |    2
17  | user16    |    8
18  | user17    |    8
```

Here in above table there is only one superuser. Which will be at the top level in hirarchy of users. This superuser is the only user who has seniorid as -1. superuser is parent of all users.
In above table every user may or may not have there child users.
The relation between parent user and child user is mentioned in table such that number in seniorid is nothing but id of the other user.

For example:

Consider following user

```
id  | username  | seniorid
18  | user17    |    8
```

in above case seniorid is 8 and so that parent of above user is

```
8   | user7 |    6
```

where as seniorid of "user7" 6 so that parent is

```
6   | user5 |    1
```

in this way doing backtracking we will get following list of hirarchy from "superuser" to "user17"

```
id  | username  | seniorid
1   | Superuser |   -1
6   | user5 |    1
8   | user7 |    6
18  | user17    |    8
```

This hirarchy will have up to n level i.e. up to many levels

I want above hirarchy result using single query.

I need your help in constructing the above query. Please can anybody give me such query in mysql.

I have id, username, seniorid of the user whose senior users list I need to find out in a single query. Here single query means It may have multiple nested querys in it. But as whole It will fired as single query.

Comment: This is not possible in MySQL in a general way, though you might be able to work around this limitation if you assumed some maximum number of levels in your query.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim Thank you sir! for your reply where to write function in mysql or in program?

Comment: Read some articles about writing stored procedures/functions in mysql.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Then you can implement `loop` cycle to stop when iterating on `seniorid` and `seniorid = -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot do this in a single query if you don't know how many levels you're going to retrieve.

If you want **n** levels, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN users u1 on u1.id = u.seniorid
LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.id = u1.seniorid
...
LEFT JOIN users u{n-1} on u{n-1}.id = u{n-2}.seniorid
WHERE u.id = 1
```

You can define a maximum number of hierarchy levels and generate such a query.

If you cannot do that, you will have to chain as many queries as there are levels...

EDIT : Like this :

```
<?php
    function addSeniors($id,&$array){
        $s = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id";
        $q = mysql_query($q);
        $results = array();
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
            $array[]=$r;
            addSeniors($r('seniorid'),$array);
        }
    }

    $s = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
    $q = mysql_query($s);
    $results = array(mysql_fetch_assoc($q));

    addSeniors($r['seniorid'],$results);
?>
```

Comment: Thank You Sir! for your reply but as you mention the its not possible in single query and I need to construct the query as mentioned by you. But in this I dont know the depth of level. So I will be unable to construct the query as mentioned by you. So is there any alternate solution to this issue like change in db structure or else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql it's better to solve this problem by using nested sets. Try to read this http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/